# Downloading files through wget getting 404 error

Tags: shell-script, wget

I am need to copy entire file from S3 to HDFS. Sample file location:
https://example.com/disabilities/state/city/MMYY/file.csv
state and city having multiple values, I need to download all csv files from all state and city. I tried

```
wget https://example.com/Disabilities/*/*/*/*_0620.csv
```

But getting error message such as No such file or directory.
How can I download?

Comment: Is the URL valid? I am really getting a 404 while trying to access it from my browser. (BTW this domain is reserved by IANA for documentation purposes)

Comment: I can't share original url, so given just sample one

Comment: Don't use `wget` for this, S3 doesn't do directory listing, there is no way for wget to retrieve the list of the files to download in the first place. Use `aws-cli` instead. `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` should meet your needs. And of course there's the authentication, if you don't want to share the original URL with us, do you want to open your storage to the public?